# Using “for” in the sense of “because”

Tags: conjunctions, word-choice

In what circumstances should it be preferable to use *for* when it has the same meaning as *because*?

Comment: "same meaning **as** *because*" -- use *than* with *different*, *as* with *same*.

Comment: Thanks @Kris for the comment. I've corrected my question.

Answer (score 7):

From [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/because-or-for.aspx):

> I was tired after my journey, for I had been forced to bike 20 miles.

However using for at the beginning of a sentence is considered bad/improper by some. To find some more specific information, please read the first link, it explains usage of for quite well. Also when for us used as a preposition, it is different.

> For instance, this sentence uses for properly.

Comment: "using for at the beginning ... considered bad/improper" -- as in "For some more specific information..."? :)

Comment: @Kris Wow... I missed that, I changed to To find. The irony :D

Comment: It's probably worth making the distinction between "for" as a conjunction and "for" as a preposition. I don't see anything wrong with "For more information, please read..." but "For Miss Ada has the softest voice, I chose her," doesn't work.

Comment: @KellyTessenaKeck Yes, great point, I added that in as we'll.

Comment: @KellyTessenaKeck That was what the smiley was for.

Comment: @MarkRobinson That was okay in fact. I meant that one needs to qualify the statement "using *for* ..." suitably. Note the smiley!

Comment: @MarkRobinson: Not sure about the "improper to start a sentence with the (preposition form) of for". For example, this sentence begins as such.

Answer (score 3):

"for" in function of "because" is a bit of antiquated though still used and rather elegant construct. You won't find it in slang often, and neither does it appear in technical-formal language, but definitely appears in formal speeches, in high society, poetry etc.

"I choose miss Ada for she has the softest voice"

Note this does not apply to replacing "because of", where "for" is just as informal:

"I choose a cheesburger for its yummy meat".

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple major differences between "for" and "because."

-As conjunctions, either works, but "for" sounds slightly formal and archaic. "I am late because the roads were very snowy this morning." and "I am late, for the roads were very snowy this morning." both work, but "because" is more commonly used.

-"For" is used as a preposition, but "because" isn't. You could say, "I stopped *for* lunch," but not "I stopped *because* lunch." In some cases, you can use "because of" but it often has a slightly different meaning than "for." (For example, if you say "I stopped because of lunch," that only tells me that lunch caused you to stop whatever you were doing. It might be that you stopped to get lunch or that you stopped doing something because other people getting lunch was interfering with it. If you say "I stopped for lunch," it's clear that you stopped to get lunch.)

Answer (score 0):

**Because** is more of an informal explanation where **for** is not.
In most cases both can be used, but when choosing, because would be more used in cases in which you think you feel need to explain yourself, when for would not.

Comment: "For Brutus is an honorable man"